# Bus Driver Bob's Dilemma

Tags: visual

It was icy and cold morning in Michigan when Mr. Busdriver Bob arrived to work. When he got into his bus he remembered Mr. Boss having told him yesterday to first pick up some students 5 miles north. Despite having lost his compass and having a poor sense of direction, Bob deduced his bus was facing north. How did he know?
P.S. Sorry for my bad artistic skills!
[image]

Comment: That's a nice detective puzzle and nice picture too. If you draw few more elements around it may look even better and harder to guess.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Thanks for the suggestion! I added a couple more details. I'll add more if I can think of them! :)

Comment: Mr. Bob probably shouldn't be a bus driver.

Comment: If Bob arrived at work, he would have to know how he got there.  If Bob is driving the bus he drove yesterday (when his boss told him about the pickup), didn't he know how he parked it?

Comment: @Keeta But you are forgetting he has a very poor sense of direction! And memory as well I'm guessing.

Comment: @ClangorousChimera If his sense of direction is so bad he doesn't know the direction he uses to arrive at work, he won't make it to work, won't be a bus driver and certainly won't make it 5 miles north to pick the kids up.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume it's as simple as it looks.

> The ice is melted on the east side of the bus because the sun rises in the east so it was likely to start melting there first.

Comment: Wow! And here I was thinking I'm clever. Nice job!

Comment: Err, wouldn't the position of the sun itself be a greater hint?

Comment: @Thomas but the suns position isn't mentioned

Comment: Anyone from Michigan knows that the sun is basically south all winter...

Comment: I figured that the sun didn't come out, since it was "an icy and cold morning", thus obviating the "the snow/ice melted first on the southeast side of the bus" response

Comment: Icy/Cold doesn't necessarily mean cloudy.

Comment: If the bus is facing north, the sun would not be shining on it and the ice would not be melting there.  In fact, the snow on top of the bus would be melting then refreezing as ice on the windshield MORE on the east side of the bus.  The ice position on the windshield is backwards.

Comment: All the snow that was added starts to contradict the initial image. I'd actually recommend @ClangorousChimera remove some of the snow because it is now misleading from what the intended answer was.

Comment: @Keeta The only way the sun isn't shining on something is if it has something bigger than it between it and the sun, or the thing is under something. Regardless of which way the bus is facing the sun will shine on it.

Comment: Alright that was my bad. I removed the snow.

Comment: @dcfyj The sun cannot shine on all sides of the bus at the same time.  If it could, we wouldn't have shadows.  The front side of the bus would have the roof and the east side of the bus between it and the bus.  Those sides would heat, but not the front face of the bus.

Comment: @Keeta True enough, but keep in mind that the bus defrosting on the east side by default is all that's needed for this puzzle. Also, vehicles do have heaters to defrost windows once the engines are started.

Comment: It doesn't work the way you are thinking.  Source: I have a CDL class B-with passenger endorsement, in Michigan.  This accepted answer is wrong.  It will not melt this way, nothing in this matches reality.

Comment: That's ok, because this is a puzzle, and as such not real.

Comment: @dcfyj It doesn't have to be real, but it's not a good puzzle if it needs to follow unmentioned rules different from reality and there is no basis for the solver to assume this.

Answer (score -4):

May be because of: 
1. lake effect, wind usually blows from north to north west/east
2. Or, birds migrating from north to south
Both giving him some sense of direction

Comment: Birds migrate in the autumn and spring, not in winter.

Answer (score -5):

Because Bob dropped the kids off the previous day, drove home in a straight line, turned the bus 180 degrees and parked up.